# Linking.openURL(url) is not working on iOS (Trying to open Whatsapp)

Tags: ios, react-native

For some reason, the linking feature to open a whatsapp contact is not working on iOS (it works perfect on Android), i followed the guide on this url for the setup https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking but always when i try to push the button that calls to whatsapp app to write a message directly, the app says something like:

*Could not open this link, please review it and try again*

The button in my screen app is this

```js
openWhatsappUrl = () => {
    const url = 'whatsapp://send?phone=+XXXXXXXXXXX';
    Linking.canOpenURL(url).then((supported) => {
      if (supported) {
        Linking.openURL(url);
      } else {
        Alert.alert(
          'Alert',
          'WhatsApp is not installed',
        );
      }
    });
  };

// This is on the render section from my screen
<DefaultButton
   title="¡Say Hi!"
   containerStyles={styles.centeredButton}
   onPress={() => this.openWhatsappUrl()}
/>
```

The AppDelegate.m file has this configuration

```swift
#import <React/RCTLinkingManager.h>
...
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
   openURL:(NSURL *)url
   options:(NSDictionary<UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey,id> *)options
{
  return [RCTLinkingManager application:application openURL:url options:options];
}
```

The Info.plist file

```xml
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
         <string>whatsapp</string>
         <string>fbapi</string>
     <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
         <string>fbauth2</string>
     <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
```

React Native version

```
System:
OS: macOS Mojave 10.14.6
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5350U CPU @ 1.80GHz
Memory: 24.91 MB / 8.00 GB
Shell: 5.3 - /bin/zsh
Binaries:
Node: 10.16.0 - /usr/local/bin/node
Yarn: 1.22.0 - ~/.yarn/bin/yarn
npm: 6.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/npm
Watchman: 4.9.0 - /usr/local/bin/watchman
SDKs:
iOS SDK:
Platforms: iOS 13.2, DriverKit 19.0, macOS 10.15, tvOS 13.2, watchOS 6.1
Android SDK:
API Levels: 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29
Build Tools: 23.0.1, 25.0.2, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.0, 28.0.1, 28.0.2, 28.0.3, 29.0.2
System Images: android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom
IDEs:
Android Studio: 3.0 AI-171.4408382
Xcode: 11.3/11C29 - /usr/bin/xcodebuild
npmPackages:
react: 16.8.6 => 16.8.6
react-native: 0.60.5 => 0.60.5
npmGlobalPackages:
create-react-native-app: 2.0.2
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
```

Comment: Can you provide a translation for the message please?

Comment: Could not open this link, please review it and try again

Comment: Judging from the docs it seems that the iPhone app doesn’t support `phone` parameter in the deep link. There is a Universal Link version that seems to support it though : https://faq.whatsapp.com/iphone/how-to-link-to-whatsapp-from-a-different-app?lang=en . Disclaimer: this is just a guess based on what I found in 5 minutes in the docs. I have not tested it, nir have I ever deep linked into whatsapp myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answer to myself, removing the plus sign from the phone number fix the error and now it works.

Comment: Is there any way to include the + sign too, though it doesn't break anything now but if a plus sign is included in a number, it is not shown in the whatsapp (e.g, +1234 will be shown as 1234). On android, i found a fix, replace + by its encoded form (%2B)